# RichTextBlock add new Blocks in loop

Tags: c#, uwp, richtextbox, windows-10-universal

I would like to add a new normal `Run` to the `RichTextBlock`, if the word doesn't match and if it matches the text should be bold:

```
if (InnerTextofCell == "TEXT")
{
   rtb2.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph (new Run { FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold, Text = innerTextOfCell }));
}
else
{
   rtb2.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph (new Run { Text = innerTextOfCell }));
}
```

The only problem I have is, `Paragraph` doesn't have a constructor which include 1 argument.

Does somebody have a solution?
Also it's in a `foreach` loop, so it repeats often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at a `Paragraph` object, you notice that the `Inlines` property (to which you add runs) is readonly. So you can't add these in the constructor. One possible solution is following:

```
var paragraph = new Paragraph();
var run = new Run { Text = innerTextOfCell };

if (InnerTextofCell == "TEXT")
{
    run.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
}

paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);
rtb2.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

You create the `Paragraph` and `Run` objects, check if the text has to be bold, and add them to the `RichTextBlock`.

Since you're talking about a `foreach` loop, you could even re-use the `Paragraph` object depending on the design you're going after (text on a single line or stacked on multiple lines). Your code would then be similar to:

```
var paragraph = new Paragraph();

foreach(...)
{
    var run = new Run { Text = innerTextOfCell };

    if (InnerTextofCell == "TEXT")
    {
        run.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    }
}

paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);
rtb2.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do this to solve your problem :

```
if (InnerTextofCell == "TEXT")
{
   rtb2.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph (new Run { FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold, Text = innerTextOfCell }));
}
else
{
   rtb2.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph (new Run { FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal, Text = innerTextOfCell }));
}
```

Comment: `"paragraph contains no constructor that take 1 argument"`, thats the error `Paragraph` throws